# Disable OutputCache on partial view mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, outputcache, asp.net-mvc-partialview

It there no way to disable partial view from being cache'd, all example mostly deal with getting it cache different from main view. i want to stop it from getting cache'd

Tried setting it to [ChildActionOnly] and Duration=0 on partial view

Also I don't want to hack it, if it could be helped.